# Enumerate Class properties without instantiating it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I list the properties of a Class *without* instantiating it?

Example:

```
class User {
  constructor({ id_user, first_name }) {
    this.props = {
      id_user,
      first_name
    }
  }
}

// Obviously won't work but you get the point
console.log(User.props) // should log id_user, first_name
```

Comment: You can't. Those properties won't get constructed untill the `constructor` get called.

Comment: Weird - I would have thought there is a way to at least get their names

Comment: you'd need to declare them as static and outside a function

Comment: The properties do not exist until the instance exists, so there is nothing to enumerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no legit way to do this without instantiating an object of that class.

With that said, what you can do, is get the actual string that is the code that describes this class with a `User.toString()` and work your way with regular expressions from there.

Comment: The `toString()` method is something I've thought of but it gets gory at that point.

Comment: Well, then there is no other way. You want to access the instance properties (that's what your example is showing, these are not static properties or prototype properties) without having an instance. There is no pretty way to do this, you'll have to spill some blood on this one

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

Any getters, setters, and methods can be enumerated like so:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {}
  get bar () { return 3; }
  baz (val) { return val + this.bar }
}

Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Foo.prototype); // lists constructor, bar, baz
```

But the way you're assigning properties in the constructor, no.